# Printing Files from Flutter App using Zebra ZQ320 Printer in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, zebra-printers

I have a Zebra ZQ320 printer and have created a PDF file using the PDF package in my Flutter app. I'm trying to print this file using the Zebra printer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: ok thanks and can you guide me how i can implement the printing functionality ?